# How do I use Dictionary as a parameter with the GET method in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Here is the URL I've tried so far:

```
{{url}}/api/items?created[gte]=1&created[lte]=1
```

And this is the GET method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/items")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItems([FromUri]Dictionary<string, int> created)
{
    var message = created["gte"];
    return Ok(""+message);
}
```

I am unable to access get data from the query parameter.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I updated the question please look at it

Comment: Why do you want to get using Dictionary parameters?

Comment: if created[lt] = 1  then I will retrieve data created before  the passed created date and if created[gt] = 1 then i will retrieve data created after the passed created date and similary if created[gte] = 1 I will retrieve data greater than equal to created date, if created[lte]=1 I will retrieve data less than or equal to created date

Answer (score 1):

You can update the method like this:

```
[HttpGet("api/items")]
public IActionResult GetItems(Dictionary<string, int> created)
{
    return Ok(created);
}
```

`[HttpGet]` also supports for `Route`.

In the url:

> https://localhost:44392/api/items?created.key1=1&created.key2=2&created.key3=3

And the result in the page:

```
{"key1":1,"key2":2,"key3":3}
```

Syntax: `created.key1=1`

- `created`: This requires a name which matches with the parameter name we typed in the method.
- `created.key1`: We create new key in this dictionary, and the key name is `key1`.
- `created.key1=1`: We define the value of the key. This value is `1`.
- `&created.key2=2`: We continue to add new key to the dictionary with the key is `key2`, and the value is `2`

... same to `&created.key3=3`